# Secure Java to MySQL database methods for sandbox applets

Tags: java, mysql, database, security, applet

I'm making a java applet that will be embedded in a browser unsigned. I've successfully allowed my applet to read from a mysql database thanks to DOM xml parsing. How I did this was using php to get data from the database and display the php file as an xml file. From there, I parsed that "xml" file.

Now I need to do this the other way around. In other words, I need my data obtained from my java applet to be stored to a mysql database.
I've spent a lot of time researching on how to do this but most of my results has something to do with jdbc, which is apparently not secure with java applets.

Thus I'd appreciate for a list of secure methods for an unsigned java applet to be able to send data to a mysql database, and links to tutorials would be the greatest. (I'm having trouble finding non-jdbc tutorials)

Is there a list of secure Java to MySQL database methods for sandboxed applets?

Comment: The point is, the JDBC should be done on the server (e.g. in a servlet), then the applet contact the servlet for access to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
So basically I need to do this:
applet <-> servlet <-> Database
I tried searching for decent tutorials but it looks like the results are limited. Can you recommend me a tutorial or website for me to learn from?
Thanks.